# Wrong rendering using CylinderGeometry and MeshPhongMaterial with vertexColors

Tags: three.js

I'm using `CylinderGeometry` to create a cylinder, and loop over its faces to set each vertex color according to the vertex y coordinate through a `rainbow` colormap. Then I use a `MeshPhongMaterial` on it, setting vertexColors to true.
I also have an `AmbientLight` and a `DirectionalLight`.

The cylinder renders correctly except on parts receiving directed light:

[image]

Please see the code here: https://codepen.io/thatcodepenaccount/pen/YzrgpYp

I looked at examples such as https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry where using `MeshPhongMaterial` with some vertex colors seems to work, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Is it because I must use `BufferGeometry`?

edit: reducing light intensity from 10 to 1 as per comment fixed it:

[image]

Comment: Try to reduce the intensity of light from 10 to 1.

Comment: @prisoner849 that fixed it, thanks! Now it looks a bit dull though (see my edit), how could I make the directed light look more intense?